When i use a command bot shouldn't tag the user of command . Is there any way to acheive this?
Hello I am a Beginner in Discord.py and i am just trying to make a confession command as practice but when i use the command it tags the user like user used /confess. is there any way to make bot not tag the user of command.
async def confess(inter: discord.Interaction, *, confession:str):
    await inter.response.send_message(confession)


If you don't want the 'user used /command' above the command, you can respond to this interaction ephemerally (only the user who invoked the command can see the message), and then send a message to the channel the command was invoked in.
async def confess(inter: discord.Interaction, *, confession:str):
    await inter.response.send_message("Only you can see this message!", ephemeral=True)
    await inter.channel.send(confession)


@PanKaJxD mind marking it as accepted if it solved your issue?
